# I sent bitcoin to someone and did not get paid

Tags: transactions, wallet, bitpay

I sent Bitcoin to someone who promised to pay me in cash personally once he received the Bitcoin in his BitPay wallet. But once he got the Bitcoin, I  never got paid by him. Is there anyway I can do something about this matter?

Comment: Sorry for your loss. This is why you need a trusted third party (e.g., coinbase.com) when exchanging a digital coin like Bitcoin for some real-world coin like US dollars. Are you sure they received the coins? Is going to the police an option?

Answer (score 3):

Does Bitcoin have a function that would allow the BTC you sent to be returned, No.

The only way to get the BTC back is if the recipient makes a new transaction sending the Bitcoin to your receiving address. If the recipient will not do this, you may think about contacting a lawyer.

Answer (score -1):

Too bad so sad, you learn a lesson.

The person could be poor and pussy and a little son of bitcoin. anyway, sorry for the loose.

Make sure to ask the person for the payment first then you send it.